# How to get the devices UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to capture when the UIInterfaceOrientation changes. I know how to do it with UIDeviceOrientation but I am wanting to prevent anything but landscape left/right and portrait.

I was using UIDeviceOrientation but every time I laid it face up everything would go crazy on my app.

So I was wanting to know how to do something like this

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];


        CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

        CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

if (interfaceOrientation landscape) {
            if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            {

             }
             else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {

             }
      }

if (interfaceOrientation Portrait) {


}
```

so I only look at either landscape or portrait.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {

}
```

It's a C function, not an objective C function.

UIInterfaceOrientation is an enum.

The other option would be:

```
if (interfaceOrientation & (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)) {

}
```

From the UIApplication.h header:

```
// Note that UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is equal to UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight (and vice versa).
// This is because rotating the device to the left requires rotating the content to the right.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown            = UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
};

/* This exception is raised if supportedInterfaceOrientations returns 0, or if preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   returns an orientation that is not supported.
*/
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientationException NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown),
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight),
};
```